# Element-wise operation using unaryExpr in Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I am trying to write a function which takes a complex valued vector and computes angles of the elements in double. My code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <complex>

class Arg {
public:
    double operator()(std::complex<double> a) const
    {
        return std::arg(a);
    }
};

template <typename DerivedA, typename DerivedB>
void ArgumentComputer(const Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedA> &mat, const Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedB> &_arg)
{

    Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedB>& arg = const_cast<decltype(arg)>(_arg);

    // 1st try:
    //arg = mat.unaryExpr(std::ptr_fun(std::arg<double>));

    //error: no matching function for call to ‘ptr_fun(<unresolved overloaded function type>)’

    // 2nd try:
    // arg = mat.unaryExpr(Arg{});

    // error: static assertion failed: YOU_MIXED_DIFFERENT_NUMERIC_TYPES__YOU_NEED_TO_USE_THE_CAST_METHOD_OF_MATRIXBASE_TO_CAST_NUMERIC_TYPES_EXPLICITLY

    // 3rd try:
    arg = mat.unaryExpr(Arg{}).template cast<double>();

    // error: invalid static_cast from type ‘const std::complex<double>’ to type ‘double’
    // return static_cast<NewType>(x);


}

int main()
{

    Eigen::MatrixXcd myMat = Eigen::MatrixXcd::Random(3, 3);
    Eigen::MatrixXd Arg_myMat(3, 3);

    ArgumentComputer(myMat, Arg_myMat);

    std::cout << myMat << std::endl;
    std::cout << Arg_myMat << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I first tried to use ptr_fun, but I guess there is a problem in resolving the type. Then I tried to write a class behaving as a functor. In this case, I got the error saying I need to do casting. When I do casting, I got static_cast error. All of the three cases are given in the code and the compiler messages are also added as comment. What are my mistakes, and how should I write it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you're unknowingly trying to cast a complex number to a real number. You see the return type of `std::arg` as `double` and assume that's what you have, but in reality it's a `std::complex<double>` because of the `mat` type (`MatrixXcd`). You're code could look like:

```
// 1st try:
//arg = mat.unaryExpr(std::ptr_fun(std::arg<double>)).real(); // Should work but doesn't resolve the template for some reason

// 2nd try:
arg = mat.unaryExpr(Arg{}).real(); // works
```

I'm not 100% sure why your first try doesn't work. You can also use functions instead of the functor:

```
double myArg(std::complex<double> a)
{
    return std::arg(a);
}
//...
arg = mat.unaryExpr(std::ptr_fun(myArg)).real();
```